# Hide text box before fetch data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want that only text filed of student registration and button show on page then Student put their number in text field and clink on Submit button so the other all fields are fetch from database sql

but but but i done all only the problem is here that on php page all things are show already like text boxes i want only one text box and submit button on page before fetch the data .

after fetch the data from mysql database the other fields text boxes will Show

here my code

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="contact" form action="mix.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="student_reg" required="required" placeholder="Student Registration Code" value="<?php echo $student_reg;?>">
</fieldset>
                        <div>
            <!-- Input For Add Values To Database-->
            
            <!-- Input For Find Values With The given ID -->
            <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="search" style="width:100%;" value="Find">
        </div>
<fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="student_name" placeholder="Name" style="border:0;outline:none;width:100%;height:100%;font-size:13px;text-align: left;" value="<?php echo $student_name;?>" readonly>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Mobile Number" style="border:0;outline:none;width:100%;height:100%;font-size:13px;text-align: left;" value="<?php echo $phone_number;?>" readonly>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You need to use Ajax. Where is your JavaScript code. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="contact" form action="mix.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="student_reg" required="required" placeholder="Student Registration Code" value="<?php echo $student_reg;?>">
</fieldset>
                        <div>
            <!-- Input For Add Values To Database-->
            
            <!-- Input For Find Values With The given ID -->
            <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="search" style="width:100%;" value="Find">
        </div>
  <?php if(!empty($student_name)) { ?>
<fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="student_name" placeholder="Name" style="border:0;outline:none;width:100%;height:100%;font-size:13px;text-align: left;" value="<?php echo $student_name;?>" readonly>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Mobile Number" style="border:0;outline:none;width:100%;height:100%;font-size:13px;text-align: left;" value="<?php echo $phone_number;?>" readonly>
</fieldset>
<?php } ?>
```